# Current name of Jatotowicze village from 1903 Russia?

Tags: poland, historical-gazetteer, place-names, belarus

I'm trying to locate the current name of the village my grandmother was born. She was born in 1903 in the village of Jatotowicze, in or near the township if Iwje, in the province of Nowogrodek. She is ethnically Polish. I believe this area is in present day Belarus.

Answer (score 5):

The answer could be [Jatołtowicze](http://www.radzima.org/pl/map/jatoltowicze.html).

From [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/53%C2%B059'06.0%22N+25%C2%B052'33.9%22E/@53.98501,25.87607,2514m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=no-NO) it looks to be a *very* small village.

Answer (score 3):

The **Geographical Dictionary of the Kingdom of Poland and other Slavic Countries** ([Słownik geograficzny Królestwa Polskiego i innych krajów słowiańskich](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/)) has two entries for [Jatołtowicze](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/?find_in=fulltext&volume_id=1&find_text=%20Jato%C5%82towicze&search_volume=all&x=0&y=0) which give the following information about Jatołtowicze:

1. It was a manor and peasant village;
2. It was in the Powiat of Oszmianski;
3. There were 86 Catholics and a Catholic Chapel in the villiage; and
4. The manor was originally in the possession of Rymaszewski but later given to the inhabitants.